# Can anyone advise which font please?

Tags: fonts

[image]Tried various online, no luck. Does anyone know? Many thanks
(apple watch series 5)

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - *Please* look through **[tour]** to get a sense of our community – who we are and what we’re about. *Then* look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see what makes a good query here, *and* how best to frame it. We have guidelines for what's on or off topic to ask here, [help/on-topic] and we some specific requirements (http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions; ***please*** take a look and [edit] then your question to meet those guidelines - thanks!

Comment: Glad to see I am not the only one who loves this font.  Would love to get access to the font so I can CNC route these fancy numbers.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/sq-al/guide/watch/apde9218b440/watchos) this font is custom designed by Apple specifically for Apple Watch. I don't know if it even has a name – the theme is called Numerals Duo – but it's probably not available as a commercial license.

[image: Screenshot from Apple Support]

Comment: Not only not available commercially, I'll bet that anyone trying to pirate or materially copy would face some serious legal heat - best to avoid if you ask me.

Answer (score -1):

This is a font made by apple and i think you should wait for some expert to make a similar 'fan' made version.

I don't think you will need to wait much.

Comment: Hi, this was already posted in the other answer, please try to not repeat info. Check [answer] if you want to learn more.

Answer (score -2):

the apple watch series font is zink font

Comment: Hi mithu, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. We typically look for substantiated answers here. Could you [edit] your answer to include some more details on _why_ you think this is the right font? Maybe add a screenshot? Thanks! Feel free to explore the site, add more answers, leave a question of your own and upvote quality content.